# New version RStudio not responding

Tags: r, rstudio

I have uninstalled old version of RStudio and installed new version. The RStudio starts with the installation of packages, hence `.Rprofile` and `.Rhistory` path is set correct.

The RStudio allows me to for instance EDIT> clear console, under `Code` in the menu bar - reacts to the Source File.. apart of that nothing! By clicking on other parts like File>Open File doesn't react.

Closing RStudio won't close and have to be closed with brute force via <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>del</kbd>, any ideas, why this is going on?

Comment: This appears to be a question for Rstudio support, not stackoverflow....

Comment: Agree with @mnel this belongs on https://support.rstudio.com

Comment: RStudio has had serious problems from the very beginning and continues to this day, often times it will hang as soon as you press save, and crash taking all your changes with it since last save, you can't really fix it, because it's a bug in the RStudio IDE itself.  R and RStudio is a bit of a trolling language/IDE combo, kind of like giving a novice carpenter a pipe wrench to bang in nails.  If he doesn't laugh along with the joke and tries, then he's not able to contribute.  R and RStudio is this pipe wrench. Have you tried restarting the IDE?  Restarting the IDE will probably fix it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Certainly the correct place to look for solution is via RStudio support. You need to however sign-in and post your question. So it takes sometime to find the cause of the problem.

If your RStudio starts but don't respond (see the description above) then:

```
1) Remove temporarily files .Rprofile and .Rhistory from your working directory
2) Install new version from scratch (Uninstall not working RStudio)
3) Start RStudio (Save and close RStudio) - it crease new files in your working directory
4) Rewrite the files with the old once and you ready to go
```